# FirebaseStorage in CloudFunctions :TypeError: storage.ref is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

iam trying to access my Storage from the Firebase cloud functions

but i cant access it

its give me

TypeError: storage.ref is not a function

and here is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.firestore();
var storage = admin.storage().bucket();
```

and my function body

```
exports.deletingVisaCop = functions.firestore.document('users/{user_Id}/info/visa_cop').onUpdate((change,context) =>{
    var userId = context.params.user_Id;
    // var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("info").doc("visa_cop");
    var data = change.after.data().state;

    var deleteData = setInterval(function () {

        var visaCopStorageRef = storage.ref();
        var ref = visaCopStorageRef.child('visa_cop');
        ref.delete().then(function(){
            console.log("Deleted")
            clearTimeout(deleteData);

            return true;
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("errorIs" + error)
        })

    }, 1000);

    if(data === true)
    {
        return deleteData;
    } else
    {
        return clearTimeout(deleteData);
    }
});
```

i want when the timer end .. the nodes in the storage delete

thank u

update

new Error

```
Error { ApiError: Not Found
    at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:193:30)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:131:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:496:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:198:7)
    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Not Found' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `var storage = admin.storage().bucket();` you are assigning to the `storage` variable the default storage bucket, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) in the documentation.

As detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket), a `Bucket` does not have any `ref()` method, hence the error you are getting when doing `storage.ref();`.

If you want to delete the bucket, just use its `delete()` method, as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#delete).

If you want to delete another bucket, i.e. the 'visa_cop' bucket, just declare it as follows and then use the `delete()` method:

```
const visaCopBucket = admin.storage().bucket('visa_cop');
return visaCopBucket.delete()
.then(function(data) {
   ....
});
```

---

Note that it is not crystal clear why you introduce a "timer" in your Cloud Function. What is the functional goal?

Comment: thank u .. and sorry because i took a long time .. but i was trying to do the ways that in the documentations that u sent to me .. but no anyway succeed .. then i found that u add a  comment and after i followed it its gave me a result i will add it in the post .. and iam adding the timer because of i want when someone change the state value in firestore .. after two days the files deleted from the storage ... thank u again

Comment: @Muhammad Any news? Where you able to try the proposed approach?

Comment: thank u for your caring .. the problem is that i found a solution for the error above but by wrongly i changed my permissions in the google cloud from an owner to another thing .. so iam trying to find a solution because i cant even access my firebase project

Comment: iam sorry .. i know that i took a long time .. but do u know how to fix this new error which i updated my post with it

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incorrect. The Firebase documentation suggests doing the following:

```
// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
var storage = firebase.storage();

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
var storageRef = storage.ref();
```

Comment: but i want to access it from admin sdk